# Syntax from jQuery to vanilla JavaScript. Function does not work the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code in jQuery:

```
$("#input").change(function(){
    var input = this;
    console.log(input);
});
```

When there is a change in the input, the element is displayed in the console as html.
I have tried to change this into plain JavaScript like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('input');
img.addEventListener( 'change' , () => {
    var input = this;
    console.log(input);
});
```

The output in the console here is the whole html document, not only the input element. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Side note; `input` isn't needed.  You already have the `img` variable to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The `this` value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for `this` which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the `this`
>   from its enclosing scope.

So, everything you need to do in this case:

```
var img = document.getElementById('input');
img.addEventListener( 'change' , function () {
    var input = this;
    console.log(input);
});
```

Comment: Alright! Thanks! I totally forgot about that and changed my code to adding an event parameter in the function and storing event.target in my input variable which I found out returns the targeted input. Thank you for clearing things out for me!

Comment: Alternatively you can keep the arrow function and access the element which raised the event from the argument passed to the handler function.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because arrow functions don't create a new scope. Change the arrow function in your second example to

```
img.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var input = this;
    console.log(input);
});
```

and it'll work exactly like your first example.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions